# ODOO - Menu dropdown_click outside to collapse

Tags: jquery, odoo, odoo-view

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-top-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse navbar-top-collapse collapse in");
        console.log("clickover: ", clickover, "_opened: ", _opened);
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle collapsed")) {
            $("button.navbar-toggle collapsed").click();
         }
    });
});
```

Any leads on this. Please help it out. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var $navbar = $(".navbar-top-collapse");               
        var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle collapsed")) {      
            $navbar.collapse('hide');
        }
    });
```